# Increment a value in xaml ListView Data template Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a simple social app, I want to increment the number of likes when a heart image is tapped, but I can't because it's in a DataTemplate. My XAML:

```
<ListView BackgroundColor="#802891" x:Name="feedList" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" HasUnevenRows="true" SeparatorVisibility="None" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5, .0, .99999, .97">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:MyViewCell>
                     <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                         <Image HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Source="{Binding imageHeart}" HeightRequest="20">
                                                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding selectImage}" CommandParameter"{Binding id}"/>
                                           </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                       </Image>
                             <Label Text="{Binding Likes}" x:Name="likesImage" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                      </StackLayout>
                </local:MyViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just update the `Likes` variable of the object behind it and the cell should update accordingly.

If that is what you do, but the value is not updated on screen, you might need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your object.

Since there is not much code added in your question, I am going to assume that your class is named `FeedItem`. Then do this:

```
public class FeedItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _likes;

    public int Likes
    {
        get => _likes;

        set
        {
            _likes = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new 
                        PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Likes)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is some optimization possible here, also be sure to check out the Microsoft Docs for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

To make your life even easier from there, you might want to look at the PropertyChanged.Fody NuGet package which can generate all the boilerplate code for you.